# Animate to one specific keyframe value of an CAKeyframeAnimation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cakeyframeanimation

I have four positions in my CAKeyframeAnimation that are part of a bezier path and my animation is working great along the path.
But now I need the animated sprite to be moved to one specific value of the keyframe position values. how could I realize that?
thnx!

Answer (score 1):

Pull the relevant values out of the CAKeyframeAnimation's keyTimes, values, and potentially timingFunctions arrays, then create a CABasicAnimation out of those.

Comment: thank you for the response! yes, i thought of that. but does the animation follow the path then to get to the keyframe position?

Comment: No, if you want to do that, follow the same logic, but create an entirely new CAKeyframeAnimation instead, with all of the keyTimes, values, and timingFunctions that you'd want.

Comment: problem is that the path is a closed bezier curve out of only four points.

Comment: I know this was a long time ago, but did you figure out a solution @headkit

Comment: I don't remember, sorry. But I guess you need to create more points on the path.